Determine all constants $k$ such that the following holds for all real numbers $x$ and $y$: $(x^2 + y^2 - k^2)(x+y)^2 + (xy-k)^2 \geq 0$
Find all values of $k \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the inequality
$$(x^2 + y^2 - k^2)(x+y)^2 + (xy - k)^2 \geq 0 $$ holds for all $\{x,y\} \in \mathbb{R}$.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is it asked to determined all real constants K with the requirements above

Note that your problem is equivalent to $x^2 + y^2 - K^2 \geq 0$, as both the $(x+y)^2$ term and $(xy+K)^2$ term are always $\geq 0$, so as long as their coefficients are positive and well defined, the equation remains true

Not equivalent, gives a sufficient condition. It seems the way to go is to "see" (thanks CAS) that $f(x,y)=(x^2+xy+y^2-K)^2-K(K-2)(x+y)^2$ which factorizes ($u^2-v^2$ form) to two ellipses.

@zwim why not equivalent? since my condition should give the same range of $k$

$-1(1)+2\ge0$, but clearly $-2\not\ge0$.

@Ayumi You need to add something e.g. source, attempt, context, etc. There are four close votes now.

I realize you want a "hand" solution, but if you're interested in how computer algebra (here, Mathematica) solves such problems instantly:

$-2 \leq k \leq 1$
And you can visualize this range as between the planes $k=-2$ and $k=1$:


What program do you use?

@Ayumi, like the man said, Mathematica.

Oh, I'm sorry i thought that was not the program. Thank you

Let:
$$ 
z=f(x,y)=\left(x^2+y^2-k^2\right)\left(x+y\right)^2+\left(x\,y-k\right)^2 
$$
Calculate local minimum & maximum 
By solving $\{{{\partial}z}/{{\partial}x}={{\partial}z}/{{\partial}y}=0\}\,$:
$$ 
\begin{cases} 
\,\frac{1}{2}\,\frac{{\partial}z}{{\partial}x}=\left(x+y\right)^3+k^2\left(x+y\right)+x^3-k\,y=0 \\[2mm] 
\,\frac{1}{2}\,\frac{{\partial}z}{{\partial}y}=\left(x+y\right)^3+k^2\left(x+y\right)+y^3-k\,x=0 
\end{cases} 
$$
Subtract $\{{{\partial}z}/{{\partial}x}-{{\partial}z}/{{\partial}y}=0\}\,$:
$$ 
\begin{align} 
&\,x^3-y^3+k\,x-k\,y=0 \\ 
&\left(x-y\right)\left(x^2+y^2+x\,y+k\right)=0 \\ 
&\implies\color{red}{x=y} 
\end{align} 
$$
Substitute in $\{{{\partial}z}/{{\partial}x}={{\partial}z}/{{\partial}y}=0\}\,$:
$$ 
\begin{align} 
&\left(2x\right)^3-k^2\left(2x\right)+x^3-k\,x=0 \\ 
&\,\,\,9x^3-x\,k\left(2k+1\right)=0 \\ 
&\left[\,9x^2-k\left(2k+1\right)\,\right]x=0 \\ 
&\implies\color{red}{x^2=y^2=x\,y=k\left(2k+1\right)/9} 
\end{align} 
$$
Apply to $\left\{f(x,y)=0\right\}\,$:
$$ 
\begin{align} 
&\left(x^2+y^2-k^2\right)\left(x^2+y^2+2x\,y\right)+\left(x\,y-k\right)^2=0 \\ 
&\left[2k(2k+1)-9k^2\right]\left[4k(2k+1)\right]+\left[k(2k+1)-9k\right]^2=0 \\ 
&(2-5k)(2k+1)+(k-4)^2=0 \\ 
&9k^2+9k-18=0 \\ 
&k^2+k-2=(k+2)(k-1)=0 \\ 
&\implies\color{red}{k=-2\,\,\,\&\,\,\,k=+1} 
\end{align} 
$$
So the local min & max $\left\{\color{red}{\forall\,x,\,y\in{{\mathbb{R}}}}\right\}$ govern 
By $k$ accord at $(k=-2)$ and $(k=+1)\,$. 
Test the ranges $\left\{k=0\,\text{shall by enough}\right\}\,$:
$$ 
f(x,y)_{\Big|_{\Large{k=0}}}=\left(x^2+y^2\right)\left(x+y\right)^2+\left(x\,y\right)^2 
$$
Hence:
$$ 
f(x,y)\ge0\implies\color{red}{-2\le{k}\le+1} 
$$
